# How to validate particular key value from array using Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My task, `appending` user selected `file` and it's `url` storing into `array` and listing `tableView` also passing values to `upload` function.

Here, Whenever I am trying to upload new file, already `stored` array files also making `duplication` upload process. So, I tried to set `status key` with some string `(like: notuploaded, uploaded).`

Initially array `index` of status key value I am setting `notuploaded` but after file uploaded I am updating status key value `uploaded`.

Whenever user trying to upload new file, I am `validating` all `array` index status key value `uploaded` or `notuploaded`. If not uploaded I am allowing to call upload `function`.

Now, my problem is first time my validation working fine but second time all the index validation falling into `positive`. But my few of the array index status key value showing notuploaded. How to validate all the index of values properly?

```
// Print array value second time
MY ARRAY: [STest.Item(url: file:///private/one.zip, title: "one.zip", status: "uploaded"), 
           STest.Item(url: file:///private/two.zip, title: "two.zip", status: "uploaded"), 
           STest.Item(url: file:///private/three.zip, title: "three.zip", status: "notuploaded")]

Already Uploaded! // Right 
Already Uploaded! // Right
Already Uploaded! // Wrong
```

Above array first two index validated well but third index wrong one because it's status: notuploaded.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let item = tableArray[indexPath.row]

        if tableArray.count > 0 {
            cell.name_label_util.text = item.title

            // Validating and uploading
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
                if self.items.contains(where: {$0.status == "uploaded"}) {
                    print("Already Uploaded!")
                } else {
                    // Calling upload function
                    self.uploadData(indexPath: indexPath, file: item.url)
                }
            })
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Remove this

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
```

as code inside `cellForRowAt` is running in main Queue by default

1- You need

```
   let item = tableArray[indexPath.row]
    if item.status == "notuploaded" {
      DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
         self.uploadData(indexPath: indexPath, file: item.url)
      })          
    } else {
        print("Item status is \(item.status)")    
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. it's working charm. I learned it from your solution. Thank you @Sh_Khan.